# change variable group_concat_max_len in SP

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a procedure which calculates some data with **group_concat** function. In some cases it fails due to default limit 1024 characters (bytes?) defined by **group_concat_max_len** parameter.

This parameter can be changed dynamically using **set session group_concat_max_len = xxx;** command.

Is it possible to change this parameter inside stored procedure for session the time procedure executes? I can't save procedure with that command.

Of course I could set it outside of the procedure, however I never know who will be running the procedure and they would always have to keep this in mind, which is basically bad approach.

If it is not possible I might have to start thinking to programmatically emulate group_concat function, which has again some disadvantages; i.e. it will be slower than native function.

Comment: Yes, you can set it in the SP.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. When I put:
set session group_concat_max_len = 15000
right after begin keyword and try to save procedure it just throws an error that syntax is wrong.

Comment: It has to be after HANDLER if you have any.

Comment: One option, try [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=118886056e0fe298547250e8050189ad).